# VC++ SetEnv.cmd in a batch file

Tags: windows, visual-c++, batch-file, cmd, setenv

I would like to do a batch file that calls `setenv.cmd` and continues with some other commands like :

```
%COMSPEC% /E:ON /V:ON /K "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd"

setenv /Release /x86
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
set MSSdk=1
python setup.py build
```

Unfortunately, the batch stops after the 1st line because it calls something close to a new `cmd.exe`.
I also tried with

```
call "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\SetEnv.cmd /Release /x86
```

but, unsuccessfully : the initial batch is still stopped after executing this `setenv.cmd`.

**What is proper way to call `setenv.cmd` and continuing a batch process ?**

Comment: `start "" setenv.cmd`

Comment: @Aacini, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `call` to run a batch script in your current context - that is to have any environment variables set their values in the parent context. ie:

```
@call "%VSCOMNTOOLS%\SetEnv.cmd"
```

**Edit**

Here is how I actually setup the compiler environment in one of our build scripts. We have a chunk of code that sets PF to the 32 bit program files path for the current system. Then call vcvars32.bat to configure the compiler environment. If SetEnv.cmd is not working for you, using vcvars is likely to be ok.

```
@rem Note: can use @call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
if "%VCINSTALLDIR%"=="" call "%PF%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
```

Comment: It finally works with using 
`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"` (then `set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1`, `set MSSdk=1`, `python setup.py build`  if I want to build a python module for example)